# Merge git tree without having to rewrite all again

Tags: git

I'm working on a project both at home and at work and certain day I forgot to push my commit at work and went on developing at home. Today I ended up with a tree like this:

[image]

However I'd like to have a **straight line** tree, since they don't have any conflicts. That was just a problem that I forgot to push. How can I solve this?

I know that I can `git reset --hard` to day 13th, but then I'll have to write again all code that I wrote after day 13th. Is there anyway to fix the git tree without having to rewrite everything?

Comment: You can create a new branch at the last blue commit before doing `git reset --hard`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to create a branch at the last blue commit before the merge. Then you can reset master and rebase:

```
$ git branch work <sha1 for last blue commit>
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard <sha1 for black commit on the 14th>
$ git checkout work
$ git rebase master
$ git checkout master
$ git merge work
$ git push -f origin master
```

**Warning:** If anyone else has already pulled your changes and is committing on top of them, then rebase will cause them a lot of headaches. You should warn all coworkers about this possibility before performing the above commands.

With that in mind, any coworkers that are working on this project can update their local repo by just fetching the repo from GitHub and resetting `master` to the correct commit:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

(Note that your work machine and home machine are equivalent to "coworkers". The above will also work to update your home machine.)

Comment: @RodrigoSouza I suggest you google "git rebase". In brief, it moves the commits from the `work` branch on top of the (reset) `master` branch to produce a linear commit history.

Comment: good it worked.. since it's already public on github, will I have to do the same at home when pulling from github?

Comment: @RodrigoSouza If I understand correctly, you followed the above steps on your work machine and now you need to get your home machine in sync. Is that correct? (I will edit my question to show how to do this.)